# Can you pre render an iframe in React so it is loaded when it is needed in the app?

Tags: html, reactjs, iframe, lazy-loading, render

In my case, I need to display a credit card form, and use an iframe to load the credit card field from CardConnect (a secure external site). The problem is that once I display that form in a modal, it takes about a half second to load that iframe. I would like to pre render/load the iframe so once it is ready to display, it looks like it loaded immediately.

I tried techniques from this link with no luck: https://hackernoon.com/lazy-loading-and-preloading-components-in-react-16-6-804de091c82d

I also tried memoizing the iframe, rendering it in a hidden div earlier in the app and calling on it again, but also no luck, it's loaded twice.

Comment: Do you find any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's been on the back burner for a while now. I'll update this question if I ever find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can show a loader by default and remove it on load of iframe.

```
<iframe onLoad={funtion to remove loader} />
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. I want it to be loaded before it is even visible.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too familiar with CardConnect however, you should be able to preload an iframe by appending the following link element to the head of your document:

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://cardconnect.com/iframe.html" as="document">
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content